# boot2docker: port forwording to manage spark workers through web UI on Mac OS

Tags: apache-spark, docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I installed boot2docker on my Mac and I use docker-compose to create a spark cluster.
Everething works fine: i run boot2docker and I create 1 spark master node and 3 spark worker node.

I connect to the spark master's web UI and I can see the 3 worker node.

Now my question is: how can I connect to the workers' web UI?

My Mac does not connect via http to the workers'web UI nodes, using the worker id link in the master's web UI page.

Comment: Can you use telnet <worker ui address or 127.0.0.1> <port>?  If you get connection refused you may need to map the port in virtual box, which runs underneath boot2docker.